# Why is Python's max() function not accurate?

Tags: python, python-2.7, max

I tried to use the [**`max()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function but I can't get the  right max with it.

Example:

```
numbers = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
a = max(numbers.split(" "))
b = min(numbers.split(" "))
print a
print b
```

Output:

```
6
-214
```

It's obviously wrong, the max should be 542. Does anyone know why `max()` fails to find the correct max value? How to get the correct answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`numbers.split(" ")` gives you a list of *strings*, not *integers*.**

---

If you want `max()` and `min()` to find the highest and lowest *integers*, then you need to convert your list of *strings* to a list of *integers* using `map(int, your_array)`.

**Example**

```
numbers = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
numbers = numbers.split(" ")  # Splits your string into a list of strings
numbers = map(int, numbers)  # Converts each element in your list to int

a = max(numbers)
b = min(numbers)
print a  # Outputs 542
print b  # Outputs -214
```

Answer (score 2):

In the other hand, you don't need to use `map` or other function to convert your string list to integer list, because it iterates over the list one more time, `max` function accepts `key` parameter, you can put a callable there, like this:

```
a = max(numbers.split(), key=int)
b = min(numbers.split(), key=int)
```

also in this case `split()` is same with `split(" ")`.

Comment: `split(" ")` is different from `split()`: `print("a b  c   d    e".split(" ")) -> ['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '', 'd', '', '', '', 'e']` vs. `print("a b  c   d    e".split()) -> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` ( if there are multiple spaces between b and c, c and d, d and e) which this comment does not display correctly: "a_b__c___d____e"

Comment: That's right @PatrickArtner, I meant in this case they are same. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Python `max()` function is accurate.

You should have a look at `numbers.split(" ")`.

It returns a list of strings. Hence, the max compares and gives the max of the *strings* in the list.

```
>>> numbers.split(" ")
>>> ['4', '5', '29', '54', '4', '0', '-214', '542', '-64', '1', '-3', '6', '-6']
```

And, as string comparisons go, it will compare the first letter of each string, and the max would be: 6.

Answer (score 0):

Because `a` and `b` are of type string, not an int.

```
numbers="4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
a = max(map(int, numbers.split(" ")))
b = min(map(int, numbers.split(" ")))
print a
print b
# 542
# -214
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
numbers="4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
a = max(list(map(int, numbers.split(" "))))
b = min(list(map(int, numbers.split(" "))))
print a
print b
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! We prefer to have some explanation along the code instead of "code-only" answers, since it will allow reader to understand the reason `why`, and not just copy-paste. Also please note that this answer does not bring anything new in comparison with other answers (same code posted by Oleg Kovalov)